# Im Trying to create a custom bot status but im getting this error again and again

Tags: discord, discord.py

This is my code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game('test" '))
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XaiZaiRo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event  
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "e:\coding\Discord Bots\Undercons\bot\main.py", line 30, in on_ready
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle , activity=discord.Game('Managing "discord.gg/crepling" '))
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'Status'
```

Comment: Do you know the version of your discord-py installation? Can you show your import statements?

Comment: Do **not** change your presence in `on_ready`, you should *not* make any API calls in that event. Set your status & activity when creating your `commands.Bot` instance instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is what you are looking for.

```
client = Bot(command_prefix=">",
             help_command=None,
             case_insensitive=True,
             max_messages=100,
             activity=Activity(type=ActivityType.watching,
                               name=f"over your server."),
             intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

It will basically say "Watching over your server." as an activity.